# How to make a UIView's subviews' alpha change according to it's parent's alpha?

Tags: ios, uiview, storyboard

I'm having trouble setting the alpha of some of my subviews.

Using Storyboard, I have a UIView,  `viewA` in my View Controller, with `subView1`, `subView2`, & `subView3` as subviews inside `viewA`.

When I change `viewA`'s alpha to 0.5, `viewA`'s alpha changes but it's subviews' alphas remain the same.

By default, shouldn't it's subview's alpha's change according to it's parents? What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
self.view.layer.allowsGroupOpacity = YES;
```

This will work for all subviews, subviews of subviews and all that.

From the docs:

```
 * The default value of the property is read from the boolean
 * UIViewGroupOpacity property in the main bundle's Info.plist. If no
 * value is found in the Info.plist the default value is YES for
 * applications linked against the iOS 7 SDK or later and NO for
 * applications linked against an earlier SDK. */
```

Your project might not be linked against the iOS 7 SDK. If you want this change to work for all views, I'd do this:

- Go to your .plist
- Add a row titled "Renders with group opacity"
- Set it to YES

From Apple's docs:

```
UIViewGroupOpacity
“Renders with group opacity”
Specifies whether Core Animation layers inherit the opacity of their superlayer. See “UIViewGroupOpacity” for details.
iOS 3.0 and later
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `subView1.alpha = subView1.superview.alpha`?

Answer (score 0):

You should check on this

[UIKit keys for Info.plist, specifically UIViewGroupOpacity.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW6)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `allowsGroupOpacity`, which can be set on the layer. There is also a global info.plist key for changing this behavior app-wide.

> When the UIViewGroupOpacity key is not present, the default value is
>   now YES. The default was previously NO.
>
> This means that subviews of a transparent view will first be
>   composited onto that transparent view, then the precomposited subtree
>   will be drawn as a whole onto the background. A NO setting results in
>   less expensive, but also less accurate, compositing: each view in the
>   transparent subtree is composited onto what’s underneath it, according
>   to the parent’s opacity, in the normal painter’s algorithm order

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-7.0/index.html